# Setting different system fonts for different languages in Debian

Tags: linux, fonts, language

I usually work with more than one language and the font that looks good in English doesn't work well with Hindi. Is there a way to make the system show me different fonts for different languages in all or most applications?

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479643/changing-font-family-for-characters-of-a-certain-language-script-using-fontconfi) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use font manager.
I use fontmatrix. Just set the preview word in the language you want, and you will see the word in every font, if possible. Give it a try.

Comment: I think the question was about configuring an user defined font for one language and using another font for another language. Your answer is about reviewing a given string using different fonts.